# How to Edit postgresql.conf on Azure PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, azure, pgadmin, azure-postgresql

I need to change `log_hostname` to off, in an attempt to fix a performance issue as recommended [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/323356/postgres-connection-establishment-slow). How do I access the `postgresql.conf` file for an Azure PostgreSQL instance?

`log_hostname` is NOT one of the parameters made available under `Server Parameters` in the GUI.

How do I edit it? Is it somehow accessible from pgAdmin?

---

Edit: Hmm, what I am asking might not be possible:

> Not all PostgreSQL parameters are available for you to reconfigure in Azure Database for PostgreSQL. If a PostgreSQL parameter is not listed in your server's Azure portal Server parameters window, then it cannot be reconfigured from the default.
>
> To review the current list of configurable parameters, navigate to the
>   Server parameters window in the Azure portal. A few Postgres
>   parameters require you to restart the server for them to take effect.
>   These are indicated by the property 'Static'

.

Comment: Can't you use `alter system`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct with you exceprt from the documentation there.

You can also use `az cli` to search through the configuration parameter details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-configure-server-parameters-using-cli

Or through the portal as you have done:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-configure-server-parameters-using-portal

But it appears that `log_hostname` is not something available to change within Azure at the moment:
[image: az cli postgres]

Comment: I am unable to connect from my local due to `server closed the connection unexpectedly
 This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 before or while processing the request.
`. Hence Add this line: listen_addresses = '*' to postgres.conf. I am unable to do so using command line. Any pointers would help if any of you have solved